# Does SQLite `NOT IN` parameter have any size limit?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite DB where I perform a query like

```
  Select * from table where col_name NOT IN ('val1','val2')
```

Basically I'm getting a huge list of values from server and I need to select the ones which is not present in the list given.

Currently its working fine, No issues. But the number of values from server becomes huge as the server DB is getting updated frequently.

So, I may get thousands of String values which I need to pass to the `NOT IN`

My question is, Will it cause any perfomance issue in the future? Does the `NOT IN` parameter have any size restriction? (like max 10000 values you can check)?

Will it cause any crash at some point?

Comment: In MySQL, there is a packet size Limit. Where are these NOT IN values coming from ? If they are from another table; you may think of Join/Subquery based approach; so that no limit affects your case

Comment: The larger the list in the IN() the slower.. Most SQL optimizers convert the `IN` list into `OR` and tends to work this way..  if the values are in sequence you better off using  `column > value and column < value` or  `column between value and value`

Answer (score 5):

This is [an official reference](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) about various limitation in sqlite. I think the **Maximum Length Of An SQL Statement** may related to your case. Default value is 1000000, and it is adjustable.

Except this I don't think any limitation existed for numbers of parameter of `NOT IN` clause.

Comment: Pretty sure it's dictated by the maximum length of a statement. At some point performance is going to be awful because parsing a huge statement takes a lot of processing time.

Comment: Recently I got the error like this. Fatal Exception: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
too many SQL variables (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR[1]): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetail WHERE accountNo NOT IN (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,

Comment: Indeed there's a limit of 999 arguments: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number

Answer (score 1):

With more than a few values to test for, you're better off putting them in a table that has an index on the column holding them. Then things like

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE col_name NOT IN (SELECT value_col FROM value_table);
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM value_table WHERE value_col = t.col_name);
```

will be reasonably efficient no matter how many records are in `value_table` because that index will be used to find entries.

Plus, of course, it makes it a lot easier to re-use prepared statements because you don't have to create a new one and re-bind every value (You **are** using prepared statements with placeholders for these values, right, and not trying to put their contents inline into a string?) every time you add a value to the ones you need to check. You just insert it into `value_table` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a limit of 999 arguments as reported in the official documentation: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_variable_number

Comment: Just to put a finer point on it, the docs say `the maximum value of a host parameter number is SQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER, which defaults to 999 for SQLite versions prior to 3.32.0 (2020-05-22) or 32766 for SQLite versions after 3.32.0.`